# top links from footer to header, not function

Tags: php, custom, store-view, toplinks

hi i have a magento withe the theme trego, by default this theme have the toplinks in footer , but i want also in header, after copy and paste the line

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(‘topLinks’) ?>
```

from footer to header, not compare the toplinks why ??

this  is the page.xml , and if notate the top link are already declared in the header.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/1column.phtml">

            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

                <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>

                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>

                <!-- Add vendor dependencies 2 -->
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/modernizr.custom.min.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/app.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/imagesloaded.js</name></action>               
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_start" as="after_body_start" translate="label">
                <label>Page Top</label>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_notices" name="global_notices" as="global_notices" template="page/html/notices.phtml" />

            <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Header</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="precontents" as="precontents"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left" translate="label">
                <label>Left Column</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
            <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
                <label>Right Column</label>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Footer</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
                <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
                <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_contact">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>contact_info</block_id></action>
                </block>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
                <label>Page Bottom</label>
            </block>
        </block>

        <block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
    </default>

    <print translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages (Print Version)</label>
        <!-- Mage_Page -->
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/print.phtml">

            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>

                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>

            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
            </block>

        </block>
    </print>

     <!-- Custom page layout handles -->
    <page_empty translate="label">
        <label>All Empty Layout Pages</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/empty.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </page_empty>

    <page_one_column translate="label">
        <label>All One-Column Layout Pages</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </page_one_column>

    <page_two_columns_left translate="label">
        <label>All Two-Column Layout Pages (Left Column)</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </page_two_columns_left>

    <page_two_columns_right translate="label">
        <label>All Two-Column Layout Pages (Right Column)</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </page_two_columns_right>

    <page_three_columns translate="label">
        <label>All Three-Column Layout Pages</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </page_three_columns>
</layout>
```

this is a header.phtml and footer.phtml : http://textuploader.com/jyqz!

i want the top links in the top bar please view image http://s3.postimg.org/m2mlx3mpf/MINI_PLECTRA_NECKLACE_Women.png

note: i use magento 1.9.1

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a naming collision because you are trying to declare 2 blocks with the same name.

In the footer section of the layout, try replacing:

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
```

with:

```
<action method="insert">
    <block>top.links</block>
    <sibling />
    <sort />
    <alias>topLinks</alias>
</action>
```

This should insert a reference to the block declared in the header section.

Comment: thanks, but not work, after replace this code , how code insert in heder.phtml ??? this ??  "<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(‘topLinks’) ?>"

Comment: Yes. In the layout file, the `<block type="page/template_links"...` should remain in the header section. The one in the footer replaced by the above. Both `header.phtml` and `footer.phtml` should contain the `echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks');` and you will need to clear your caches.

Comment: i have insert you code in app/design/frontend/default/trego/layout/page.xml

Comment: this is a result http://textuploader.com/qa9j!, after this  i have paste <?php echo $this->getChildHtml(‘topLinks’) ?>     in app/design/frontend/default/trego/template/page/html/header.phtml. it's true ??